# How to do exponential curve fit for a set of data using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, curve-fitting, exponential

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do an exponential curve fit for this set of data. I've looked at quite a number of other posts and tried doing it other ways but in the end, I could never get it to work. Please try to simplify things as much as possible because I have very little experience with coding.

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)

x = arrx
y = arry
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
xFit = np.arange(0.0, len(x), 1)
plt.plot(xFit, func(xFit, *popt), 'r', label='fit params: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.show()
```

[image: The graph I get from the following code is shown below]

The red line should be my curve fit but I'm very inexperienced so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Where is the `curve_fit` function defined?

Comment: I imported curve_fit from scipy.optimize if that is what you mean

Comment: ...try a reasonable `P0` : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html